# how to put the view in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is my `Controller` coding in zend framework

```
public function homeAction() {

    $storage = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();
    $data = $storage->read();
    if (!$data) {
        $this->_redirect('admin/login');
    }
    $this->view->storeid = $data->storeid;
    $iExtStoreId = $data->storeid; // admin storeid

    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $sql = "SELECT storeId FROM stores where extStoreId= '$iExtStoreId' ";

    $result = $db->fetchAll($sql);
    $sStoreId = $result[0]['storeId'];
    if (strlen($sStoreId) >= 32) {
        $sql = "select * from voucherRedemptions where storeId='$sStoreId'";

        $result2 = $db->fetchAll($sql);
    } else {
        $result2 = array();
    }
    echo "<table border='1'>
                        <tr>
                        <th>redemptionId</th>
                        <th>voucherId</th>
                        <th>storeId</th>
                        <th>redemptionTime</th>
                </tr>";

    if (count($result2) > 0) {
        foreach ($result2 as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['redemptionId'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['voucherId'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['storeId'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['redemptionTime'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>Data not found </td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

now I want to keep the view `code` in `view` folder `home.html` `what i can do ?`

Comment: Why are you printing `view` stuff in your controller?

Comment: You are doing it *so* wrong. As PeeHaa says, you shouldn't have view stuff (HTML) in your controller. Zend Framework is very MVC-orientated, and you are completely *not* following the MVC pattern which is why you're having problems.

Comment: @MartinBean /media/New Volume_/admin/application/views/scripts/admin/home.phtml I want to keep here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `echo` all that stuff in the controller. That's what the `view` is for.

After setting all the viewvariables do:

```
$this->render('/path/to/home.html');
```

And print all the stuff there.

Also note that the Zend Framework has [pretty good documentation available](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too up-to-speed with Zend Framework, but going on PeeHaa's answer and my sketchy knowledge, I'd guess your controller would look like this:

```
class YourController {

    public function indexAction() {
        $view = new Zend_View();
        $view->someVar = 'Some Value.';
        $view->render('/admin/admin.phtml');
    }
}
```

And then in your `admin.phtml` template:

```
<!-- should output "Some Value." -->
<p><?php echo $this->someVar; ?></p>
```

Comment: You don't need this line `$view = new Zend_View()` as actions have a view object by default. In fact you don't need `$view->render()` either as all that is done automagically so long as you have your view script in the default location.